# startswith in python not returning as expected

Tags: python

I have a json file called `response`:

```
{

    "id": "163698b3-1e6b-4087-b398-16e2f5b1e7ef",

    "status": "Submitted"

  },

  {

    "id": "ed433b9e-ea4e-4652-907e-03114f869774",

    "status": "Submitted"

  },

  {

    "id": "3cd662fb-afdd-47e1-abde-364d727cfdab",

    "status": "Submitted"

  }
```

I search for the lines that start with `status`:

```
search = '"status"'

with open('path/to/file') as response:
    for line in response:
        if line.startswith(search):
            print(line)
```

And I get no output, why is that ? My final goal is to remove this line. thanks.

Comment: It looks to me like the line starts with spaces. Do you have to use python for this? There's a cli tool called [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) that's great for stuff like this.

Comment: None of the lines in your example data start with the text `"status"`. The lines that contain that text start with whitespace. But if you goal is to extract data from a JSON file, you should just be using the `json` module instead.

Comment: If you have to you python, why not first deserialize it into a python object with `json`, as larsks suggests?

Comment: ok nice suggestions, will try it out ! thanks

Comment: @xdhmoore yeah I've used `jq` just a little bit , happy to know a `jq` answer for that

Comment: Actually, you could probably even just use `sed`, if it's all formatted like the above and you just need something quick and dirty...

Comment: yeah, in `jq` I think it's the `del()` command

Comment: yeah true @xdhmoore, I was just polishing python skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code：

```
search = '"status"'
with open("test.json", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open('test.json', "w") as response:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.lstrip().startswith(search):
            print(line)
            response.write(line)
```

Result:

```
{

    "id": "163698b3-1e6b-4087-b398-16e2f5b1e7ef",


  },

  {

    "id": "ed433b9e-ea4e-4652-907e-03114f869774",


  },

  {

    "id": "3cd662fb-afdd-47e1-abde-364d727cfdab",


  }
```